# IIS Web site vs Application

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

In IIS I can convert a folder in a website into an application... but how to do you make the root website an application?

Right now if I have an application (let's call it foo), the only way I know to get it running in IIS is to create a website (we'll call it bar.com) and then add the application under the website so that I have to access it by navigating to http://bar.com/foo.  How can I set it up to navigate to the app when simply navigating to bar.com?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> but how to do you make the root website an application?

The root website is already an application. So basically when you have a website, this website is mapped to a physical location on the hard disk which is where you should deploy your code. Then if the website has a binding with `bar.com:80`, your application will be directly accessible on `http://bar.com`.

Comment: Ah... good to know :)  Although, that means there's clearly a problem with my app but at least I definitely know the problems is with the app now.  Thanks!

Comment: Darin, if I set the binding of the website to 'monitor' over port 80 then when I type http://monitor (on that machine) then it should go to the website, right?  That doesn't seem to work, though making it an application inside the Default website does let me go to it via http://localhost/monitor.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Something's still missing.  I set the binding to my new website to localhost just to rule out binding issues I might not understand.  If I put the iisstart.htm file in the root it displays fine, but without it I get a 503 error and my mvc application simply doesn't work.

Comment: What if there is several applications inside website?